# Userform to search for two criteria, then paste row's data to userform textboxes

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am getting a run-time error '13': type mismatch for one of the lines marked below. I want to be able to have a userform that you can type two criteria into, then it will search for the row that has both of those criteria and paste the corresponding cells' values to the 11 userform textboxes. I'm not sure why it is giving me an error for this line, or if there is a better way to do this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    txt1.Visible = True
    txt2.Visible = True
    txt3.Visible = True
    txt4.Visible = True
    txt5.Visible = True
    txt6.Visible = True
    txt7.Visible = True
    txt8.Visible = True
    txt9.Visible = True
    txt10.Visible = True
    txt11.Visible = True

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("The Goods")
    ws.Activate

    Dim SearchSearch As Variant
    SearchSearch = txtsearch.Value
    Dim SearchName As Variant
    SearchName = txtname.Value


        If Trim(txtsearch.Value) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Search can't be left blank.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Search"
        End If
        If Trim(txtname.Value) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Name can't be left blank.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Name"
        End If

    Dim FirstAddress As String, cF As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("The Goods").Range("D:D") 'txtsearch will be in the range D:D

        Set cF = .Find(What:=SearchSearch, _
                       after:=ActiveCell, _
                       LookIn:=xlValues, _
                       LookAt:=xlPart, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                       MatchCase:=False, _
                       SearchFormat:=False) ' line that is giving me an error

     With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("The Goods").Range("B:B") 'txtname will be in the range B:B

        Set cF = .Find(What:=SearchName, _
                       after:=ActiveCell, _
                       LookIn:=xlValues, _
                       LookAt:=xlPart, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                       MatchCase:=False, _
                       SearchFormat:=False)

        txt1.Value = cF.(0, 5).Value 
        txt2.Value = cF(0, 3).Value 
        txt3.Value = cF(0, 6).Value 
        txt4.Value = cF(0, 7).Value 
        txt5.Value = cF(0, 8).Value 
        txt6.Value = cF(0, 9).Value 
        txt7.Value = cF(0, 10).Value 
        txt8.Value = cF(0, 11).Value 
        txt9.Value = cF(0, 12).Value
        txt10.Value = cF(0, 13).Value 
        txt11.Value = cF(0, 14).Value 

    End With
End With

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim iExit As VbMsgBoxResult
iExit = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Search System")

If iExit = vbYes Then
Unload Me
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `txtsearch`?

Comment: Thats the first textbox that you're looking for the matching row for. `txtname` is the second textbox that you're looking for the matching row. After you enter these two values on the userform, then you hit the command button to have all the textboxes populate

Comment: Change `Dim searchSearch as Variant` to `...as String`, do you still get an error? Try replacing the "What" with a string, not a variable, just to double check that bit is working.

Comment: @BruceWayne that didn't change anything so still an error at the `Set cF =.Find...`  line

Comment: If the active cell is not inside the search range you will get an error. You can remove that bit anyway. Also don't think you can nest With statements like that.

Comment: Do you know a different way I could get the mission accomplished with having two values I want to search, since the With statements need to be reworked? @SJR

Comment: Just kidding it worked just by deleting the active cell part! Thanks!! @SJR

Comment: This doesn't really work since there's nothing ensuring the search terms are found on the same row...

Comment: Why are you doing two searches and assigning to the same variable? That will not work as intended.

Comment: Then how do I make it know that the second criteria must be in the same row? If you could please provide code, I would appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is a simple `For Loop`, which loops through each `cel` in `Column B` and checks for `txtname.Value`, and  using offset to check if `Column D` value is equal to `txtsearch.Value`.  If both match, then it will write the values for that row into the `userform` text boxes. You can change the `TextBox1` to `txt1`, etc.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet, cel As Range

Set ws = Sheets("The Goods")


    For Each cel In ws.Cells(2, 2).Resize(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Cells

        If cel.Value = Me.txtname.Value And cel.Offset(, 2).Value = Me.txtsearch.Value Then

            Me.TextBox1.Value = cel.Offset(, 3).Value 'Change to your textbox naming scheme
            Me.TextBox2.Value = cel.Offset(, 1).Value
            Me.TextBox3.Value = cel.Offset(, 4).Value
            Me.TextBox4.Value = cel.Offset(, 5).Value
            Me.TextBox5.Value = cel.Offset(, 6).Value
            Me.TextBox6.Value = cel.Offset(, 7).Value
            Me.TextBox7.Value = cel.Offset(, 8).Value
            Me.TextBox8.Value = cel.Offset(, 9).Value
            Me.TextBox9.Value = cel.Offset(, 10).Value
            Me.TextBox10.Value = cel.Offset(, 11).Value
            Me.TextBox11.Value = cel.Offset(, 12).Value

        End If

    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a run-time error '1004': application-defined or object defined error for the line `If cel.Value = Me.txtname.Value And cel.Offset(, 2).Value = Me.txtsearch.Value Then`. It is showing the cel=Nothing @GMalc

Comment: `Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` needs a worksheet qualifier...

Comment: Adding `ws.` now gives run-time error '438': object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: @Tara, updated to include the worksheet variable. If your textbox names are not the same as the basic names in this code, you will need to change the textbox names in the code to match your textbox names. I don't usually change the textbox names because I'm lazy.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late reply @GMalc

Comment: @tara you should accept the answer if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim i As Long, rngB As Range, n As Long, arrB, arrD
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SearchSearch As Variant, SearchName As Variant

    For i = 1 To 11
        Me.Controls("txt" & i).Visible = True
    Next i

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("The Goods")
    ws.Parent.Activate
    ws.Activate

    SearchSearch = Trim(txtsearch.Value)
    SearchName = Trim(txtname.Value)

    'check the trimmed values
    If Len(SearchSearch) = 0 Or Len(SearchName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "'Search' and 'Name' can't be left blank.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Search"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'get search ranges
    Set rngB = ws.Range(ws.Range("B1"), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    Set rngD = rngB.Offset(0, 2)

    'pull the values into a couple of arrays for faster searching
    arrB = rngB.Value
    arrD = rngD.Value

    'loop over the arrays
    For n = 1 To UBound(arrB, 1)
        If arrB(n, 1) = SearchName And arrD(n, 1) = SearchSearch Then
            'got a hit - populate your textboxes

            Set cF = rngB.Cells(n, 1)
            txt1.Value = cF.Offset(0, 1).Value  'Col C same row
            txt2.Value = cF.Offset(0, 2).Value  'Col D same row
            txt3.Value = cF.Offset(0, 3).Value  'Col E same row
            'etc etc

            'OR do something like this:

            With rngB.Cells(n, 1).EntireRow
                txt1.Value = .Cells(1, "C").Value
                txt1.Value = .Cells(1, "D").Value
                txt1.Value = .Cells(1, "E").Value
                'etc etc
            End With


            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If cF Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No match!"

End Sub
```

Comment: When I run that code with slight edits for values relative to my file, then I get "compile error: expected array" for `To UBound(rngB,1)`

Comment: RngB >> arrB Sorry typo

Comment: When I change `UBound(rngB,1)` to `UBound(arrB, 1)` then I do not get any errors, but no information is pasted onto the userform @Tim Williams

Comment: Sorry I'm sure this is super simple, but I am trying `txt1.Value = cF(n, 5).Value` or `txt1.Value = cF(0, 5).Value` for the part that is relative to my file, if that is what is messing it up @Tim Williams

Comment: Updated with a couple of different approaches

Comment: Unfortunately, with either method it's still not pasting anything to the userform, but also not giving an error message @Tim Williams

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging - put some breakpoints and see whether it finds a match, and then step through from there.